# How to replace values of an array with another array using numpy in Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I want to place the array B (without loops) on the array A with  starting index A[0,0]

```
A=np.empty((3,3))
A[:] = np.nan
B=np.ones((2,2))
```

The result should be:

```
array([[  1.,   1.,  nan],
       [  1.,   1.,  nan],
       [ nan,  nan,  nan]])
```

I tried `numpy.place(arr, mask, vals)` and `numpy.put(a, ind, v, mode='raise')` but I have to find the mask or all indexes.

How to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assign it where you want using indexing

```
import numpy as np
A = np.empty((3,3))
a[:] = np.nan
B = np.ones((2,2))
A[:B.shape[0], :B.shape[1]] = B



array([[1.00000000e+000, 1.00000000e+000, nan],
       [1.00000000e+000, 1.00000000e+000, nan],
       [nan, nan, nan]])
```

Comment: How did you get all those `nan` in `A`?

Comment: ops, didn't run it and didn't remember how `np.empty` works. Fixed it